# Посчитать длину числа и количество четных цифр в нём

Tags: c++

Данный код должен принимать число и считать его длину, количество четных цифр, а также выдать их процент в числе, но данный код не считает числа длиннее 10 цифр, почему?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int countNumber(int numb) {
    int count = 0;
    int countEven = 0;
    while (numb > 0) {
        if ((numb % 10) % 2 == 0) {
            countEven++;
        }
        numb = numb / 10;
        count++;
    }
    cout << "Count numbers " << count << endl;
    cout << "Count even numbers " << countEven << endl;
    cout << "Percent of even numbers " << (double(countEven) / double(count)) * 100;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int numb;
    cout << "input numb\t";
    cin >> numb;
    countNumber(numb);
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в отладчике что у вас там происходит...

Comment: Делай всё с `string`

Answer (score 7):

Ваш код работает с типом `int`, который обычно имеет размер 4 байта, и максимальное представимое им значение - немного более 2 миллиардов.

Если использовать `unsinged long int`, то получите примерно 18 цифр.

А вообще в вашей задаче имеет смысл считывать число как строку, и работать с цифрами как символами строки.

Что-то типа

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Input number: ";
    string n;
    getline(cin,n);

    int count = 0, even = 0;
    for(auto c: n)
    {
        if (!isdigit(c))
        {
            cerr << "Not a number!\n";
            return 1;
        }
        int digit = c - '0';
        if (digit % 2 == 0) even++;
        count++;
    }
    cout << "Digits: " << count << endl;
    cout << "Even digits: " << even << endl;
}
```

`count` вообще-то не нужен, это просто длина строки, но я сделал максимально похоже на ваше решение.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если рассуждать логически тип у тебя int
А int находится в диапазоне(−2 147 483 648;2 147 483 647) Тут десятизначное это предел. Возможно ты выходишь за границы. А так надо бы приложить фото ошибки.